# How to parse invidual line of a text file?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    
    try {
        List<String> line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt"));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner((Readable) line);
        List<FogDevice> fogdevices =new ArrayList<FogDevice>();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String data[]=scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            System.out.println(data);
            fogdevices.add(createFogDevice(data[0],Boolean.parseBoolean(data[1]),Long.parseLong(data[2]),Integer.parseInt(data[3]),Double.parseDouble(data[4]),Double.parseDouble(data[5]),Double.parseDouble(data[6])));
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(fogdevices);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private static FogDevice createFogDevice(String name2, boolean x2,long mips2,int ram2, double ratepermips2,
        double busypower2, double idlepower2) {
--------
---------some activity-----
return fogdevice ;
}
```

Format of demo.txt :

```
FD1,true,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25
FD0,false,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25
```

i want output in the below form by using createfogdevice function.

```
fogdevice1 : FD1,true,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25
fogdevice2 : FD0,false,102400,4000,0.01,103,83.25
```

Comment: You split on space, but the input has commas - that's not a good start.

Comment: i changed it to comma, still getting unresolved compilation problem. can you please tell where it is getting wrong ?

Comment: Include the exact compiler error or stack trace you get, and make sure the line numbers match up or otherwise ensure that us question answers can figure out which line that stack trace or compiler error is referring to.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at org.fog.examples.demo.main(demo.java:62)       at main function i am getting this error @rzwitserloot please help

Comment: You don't really have the lines `--------` and `---------some activity-----` in your actual code, do you?

Comment: no by --- i mean there is a piece of code at that place .

Comment: OK, then.  By your stack trace the problem is at line #62.  Guessing that `Scanner scanner = new Scanner((Readable) line);` is line #62, yes?

Comment: at line 62, i am having public static void main(string[] args)throws IOException{

Comment: @KevinAnderson can i discuss by sharing the code screen ?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to run code that didn't even compile properly.  You should have seen a compiler message (or several) for the line  `Scanner scanner = new Scanner((Readable) line);`

Comment: Share anything you think will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're confusing and mixing two different approaches to reading a file line-by-line.    You started off using the `nio` method `readAllLines`, and then tried to switch gears to a `Scanner` and `nextLine()`.

Either approach will work, you just have to pick one and stick with it.

So, if you like like `readAllLines`:

```
        try {
            List<String> line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt"));
            List<FogDevices> fogdevices = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String l : line) {
                String data[] = l.split("\\s*,\\s*");
                System.out.println(data);
                fogdevices.add(
                    createFogDevice(
                        data[0],
                        Boolean.parseBoolean(data[1]),
                        Long.parseLong(data[2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(data[3]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[4]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[5]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[6])
                    ));
            }
            System.out.println(fogdevices);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Or if you prefer to go with `Scanner`:

```
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt"));
            List<FogDevices> fogdevices = new ArrayList<FogDevices>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String data[] = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*");
                System.out.println(data);
                fogdevices.add(
                    createFogDevice(
                        data[0],
                        Boolean.parseBoolean(data[1]),
                        Long.parseLong(data[2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(data[3]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[4]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[5]),
                        Double.parseDouble(data[6])
                    ));
            }
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println(fogdevices);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```